# How to do Oracle style numbered logging?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

In oracle one often gets messages like -

```
ORA-01882: timezone region not found.
```

This format has several benefits like -

1. Easier to provide phone support, client only has to read out the error code.
2. Easier to search for and count a particular error in a file. Instead of searching log messages with regex based pattern matching I could just search for the unique error code.

**How can I pull this off in my own application? I'm not just asking for a code snippet but how would you manage the whole process.**

1. Would you maintain the mapping of error codes to messages in an Excel, Properties File or DB?
2. Do I need to enter each code-message combo manually into DB before using it? Can I have my logging framework automatically create a random error code for each unique string that I log?
3. Is there a standard provision for this in popular logging frameworks like logback?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a key for every error type which you have to determine.  [ResourceBundles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) can help you.  Once reason to use it is language support.  The text can be in any language provided you provide a file for each language.

Answer (score 0):

1. Properties if you want I18N support.
2. Particular section of code can have a particular number error if exists.
   e.g. Apache Derby has a interface with a list of error message identifiers. This is the set of message identifiers.

   ```
   String CONNECT_PASSWORD_ISNULL = "08001.C.8";
   String CONNECT_SOCKET_EXCEPTION = "08001.C.3";
   ```

   This indentifiers is using in some sections of [code](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.5/org.apache/derby/10.1.2.1/).

   ```
   throw Util.generateCsSQLException(SQLState.CANNOT_COMMIT_XA);
   ```
3. Log in your favourite framework. e.g. MyBatis use custom loggin classes for log to several frameworks, the class [`org.apache.ibatis.logging.LogFactory`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mybatis/mybatis/3.0.1/org/apache/ibatis/logging/LogFactory.java?av=f) have that logic.